# How can I prevent "Application is not responding" dialog?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 23.10

I have an application which causes GNOME to pop up this dialog repeatedly. If I click the Wait button, it carries on for a short while, then pops up again. I have pressed this button a dozen or more times, and the application does indeed complete successfully.

[image: python3 is not responding dialog]

How can I prevent this, or massively increase the delta time between one occurrence and the next?

Comment: Does this application need human interaction once it is started? I see this pop-up only when I try to interact with a frozen app. If I leave the keyboard and mouse alone or move the focus to another app, the pop-up either does not pop up or does not do anything. Even if I don't click the **Wait** button "a dozen times" pop-up will eventually go away once the app is responsive again.

Comment: No, I do not need to interact with it once the process is started. I'm waiting for it to finish building a local database. It takes a while to do this, while it queries a remote server. It does finish, and it's not crashing or hung, it's just a long job. I don't want the popups to appear, even if the application is working, because it obscures the window, so I cannot see the progress the application is making.

Comment: @JohnCarterI will try that, thanks.

Comment: @popey thanks for the clarification. You may want to add that to the question, but it may turn out to be a duplicate after all.